# What can I do when args[0] is not working? JDA Builder

Tags: java, discord-jda

I tried to code a Discord Bot with JDA but when I try to start the program, it doesn´t work.

Here is my Code:

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, InterruptedException {
        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(args[0]);
        builder.setToken("token");
        builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        
        
        
        builder.build();
    }
}
```

This is the Console Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 at de.DiscordBot.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I think the problem is at (args[0]) but I am not sure.

Comment: Well it sounds like your program isn't being provided with any command-line arguments... how did you try to provide one?

Comment: "I think the problem is at (args[0]) but I am not sure." You can make sure by looking at the line number: `Main.java:15`.

Comment: Adding to what @JonSkeet has mentioned, command-line arguments are provided when you run your code from the command line. It should look something like 'java Main inputValue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, in a `main` method, you need to check the length of your input array. If you start your program without any arguments then args will be empty.

Generally, I'll do something along the lines of

```
if (args.length>0) {...}
```

because that protects you from `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.